# union return type in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

trying to use typescript in a way it is not potentially designed, would like some guidance:

I made a useGet hook in react, which returns one of the following types:

```
type Res<T> = [T, false, false] | [null, true, false] | [null, false, true]
```

when I return my hook result like so:

```
return [data, loading, error]
```

i get the following error:

```
Type '[T | null, boolean, boolean]' is not assignable to type 'Res<T>'.
  Type '[T | null, boolean, boolean]' is not assignable to type '[null, true, false]'.
    Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
```

I don't understand what the problem is here. I was hoping that a later check of `if (!loading)` then typescript would interpret `data` as `T`

maybe I am asking too much...

thanks!

full hook code: https://gist.github.com/ELI7VH/8321bc65e213665569e9c97684f21255

Comment: Yes, I think you're asking too much. The destructured variables' types are no longer dependent on each other. What might work is `if (!arr[1] && !arr[2])`, but a safer bet would be a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)

Comment: Also, `if (!loading)` will *not* infer `data` to `T`, you'd have to check for `if (!error)` as well

Comment: thanks, yep, that was a brain fart for me, That's what I meant originally. (if no loading or error, happy data)

Comment: Oh wait now I realise that this question was about the `return` statement in inside the hook, not the usage of the variables outside. Good I wrote only comments :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loading` and `error` are both of type `boolean`. This means that (as far as the type system is concerned), both could be `true` which isn't allowed by `Res<T>`. You may have logic that prevents that case, but the type system can't really know this.

If you want the strong typing of those tuples in the union, I think you should use runtime logic to explicitly return each case.

```
  if (data) {

    // Has data, done loading, no error.
    return [data, false, false]

  } else if (error) {

    // No data, done loading, there was an error.
    return [null, false, true]

  } else {

    // No data, loading in progress, no error yet.
    return [null, true, false]

  }
```

Now typescript can verify the right tuples are returned by all conditional branches.

---

Or you could just type Res as `[T | null, boolean, boolean]`, but this has the drawback of not being able to infer the other members from one member.

That means you could not do this:

```
declare const res: Res<any>
if (res[1]) { // typescript now knows this tuple is: [null, true, false]
  const a = res[0] // typescript knows this is null
  const b = res[2] // typescript knows this is false
}
```

But you could with the first approach.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUBUEkBldAQVAdWgBQFAEsC2AHAewCcAXUAb1AFcBnAU3FIENT6AaGhgUQDNf6AY3IBfUL2KFcoAOTF6zYTJwES5KnXoBVBsQDChAHZsAHqPGTpMwUdOlawHfX236Z5XiJkkJ7IVoWUrLMvv4eqt5UALIA8noA0gD6iOjQoGISQTLM+NjAuISCANbhXupc9IjUpAAWBsZu5plWNg1mDlW19XbKmKQAnvj0oABK9LQAPJAAfKAAvKAA2pCcvMwANgyrGwwAuqAAPkuG1OvrnKTE1BziO-T7R4snZ9ubN5fXu5h9g8MAitdiP10MxiMxpAtFrRLthDABzTjQ4iwuH7ECgIr0fqgABuG2u3wGQ1AMXwpD8hgCCwomFAoFo1AARrRBMjGfQAFygRmEQjrBSGWmgGzUYxck64dnEUDo0Fg7GwgAmblA-PhtSF+FB4NoAH4uQDnMDtbhFl8RITfqAAFK0IwpaBTWbUoXQ1h0cXUSXOIXKljYdZcpEo32sZhcyBC8mkflBmHwzAWn7E8BMlnIskUkH9daEZiKibgZ2UUMsLngGVgWgo-mgQiMgBWQnIBWhquwmPW-SFzkkxC53GIfcT33RkBiABEYlzNABxeikGKGYYAMgq89IUWYhmx7MEzE0oHsAFpsHDDCRhoz86OwBXsAEjF3xCRQAB3Gr0QxcFH0tOs7BMyMTA3DKYUjDbOcF3mUApk4CsFm3fppgACi-RUiFhUg42ReFOEIIDKX1ElCNoABKLkxkmGZ5lmGk6VaNsNF0dIYM0JwXDaUgULIoVGPIA9ajYhhOjqVwzB4viIPIRZFTDREFwnMN9gWTQmFYegpkOUBnnWVDdN4hjpKWXN8xRBTSFgPNFRRFSKnUtgUI+ehDPAykZN7EgLMHPs7LUlhHLWN5XKFTQ+AEYQUJ42iSzpIz3NAOFoMQ2h+kMQRQGiuY6KFOKjyBWK8ri9EkvIdDMOMStQHzRVwNFchSEIUAAEdAWxLUwVwWhcqK-iaGIdYYIAA2AHEAEZgAAEgocrCCwkQhp6vK+o6nUYII8kIN1AA6Vaup23AciixYik4HFdjImKhumooRDmaacREFchtcoq3KY0A5JYVjELfZhsHIRBQlobbSomW17VSJ1UOoAbQAAakyvaAl1UAht1abkYW0AuRkGQyN4pa4oYUglJYFCvuYbbKdeoqSassz4RQoKGFpukxH3UhBBqTLPOIS76Le+lFLDFCDKJul6eslFmbuNniYXHySCcq4XKJi08qTPLSskvLsF4TKNopPVtoZZkAPZAWifREm-3NtlnGFgThApI8mpqbdFX5LR8C++geo19JOEWWasPw0jOE0YhOEEmoLu+Ol9cymnCrpeRSFh79ZPk243lePYhTEeg3lAJO0KHEgrby9PM+OU5zlzrZ8s+QvQGLhhU9AGviCz3SLlV-P7kLkdvmVQR1lBYY+vkWhKPGCYKHDHSvSlERphwA2UJnxYxouwq+uYGDt4ABjRMAiXGACyQxC83wCWoH1LgJdKkhLGSP8ZFgAJjPo9fnTQC5Aii33vjUR+j8Wb+xEEAA)

Comment: thank you. very helpful (the second suggestion was the one I was using before I tried to smarten it up)

One thing to note that I just realized, if the values are destructured on the way out, typescript loses it's grasp on the overall type.

so the use case has to be 
`const res = useGet<SomeType>('some-path')`
rather than:
`const [data, loading, error] = useGet`

Comment: Yep, you only really gain value from a union of tuples like this if you are _not_ using destructuring, sadly. Once each value in its own variable, typescript no longer believes the values to connected by the type system in any way.

Comment: got it. I actually changed it to return an object so it's a bit more intuitive to use: `const records = useGet('records')` then `if (records.loading) return <Loading />`... etc

Answer (score 2):

A check for if (!loading) will cause typescript to interpret loading as false. But it won't change the way it interprets data.

```
if (loading) {
    // loading is true
    // compiler won't complain about next line
    return [null, loading, false];
}
if (error) {
    // error is true
    // compiler won't complain about next line        
    return [null, false, error];
}
// error is false
// loading is false
// Still no assertion about data
if (data) {
    // data is T
    return [data, loading, error];
}
// There is no valid return type here
// May be throw exception here cause data is not T and both loading and error are false
throw new Error("No data, error is false and loading is false");
```